# Xerces C++ unresolved linker error

Tags: c++, xml, windows-7, visual-studio-2005, xerces-c

I'm using VS2005 to generate and build Xerces .hxx/.cxx files for a schema I created.  I'm able to generate the schemas and compile them but upon linking I received the below linker errors.  I included xerces-c_3D.lib into the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies tab. And it seems to find it.  Because when I take out the location from Linker->General->Additional Library Directories VS complains that it can't find xerces-c_3D.lib

I've used http://wiki.codesynthesis.com/Using_XSD_with_Microsoft_Visual_Studio to setup the project.

I've also tried building one of the example applications and after setting up the includes and libraries it builds without fail.  I even built and did the same thing in vs 2010 and it works.  So I'm at a loss as to where to look.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ProjectBlue, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>UniqueID.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall xsd::cxx::zc_istream_base<char>::zc_istream_base<char>(class xsd::cxx::ro_string<char> const &)" (??0?$zc_istream_base@D@cxx@xsd@@IAE@ABV?$ro_string@D@12@@Z)
1>Arch.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>ArchDetails.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>ArchType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>TSPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_NONAMESPACESCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>UniqueID.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>Arch.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>ArchDetails.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>ArchType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>TSPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION" (__imp_?fgXSI_SCHEMALOCACTION@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>UniqueID.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgURI_XSI" (__imp_?fgURI_XSI@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>Arch.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgURI_XSI" (__imp_?fgURI_XSI@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB) referenced in function "public: class std::_Vector_const_iterator<class xercesc_3_1::DOMAttr *,class std::allocator<class xercesc_3_1::DOMAttr *> > & __thiscall std::_Vector_const_iterator<class xercesc_3_1::DOMAttr *,class std::allocator<class xercesc_3_1::DOMAttr *> >::operator+=(int)" (??Y?$_Vector_const_iterator@PAVDOMAttr@xercesc_3_1@@V?$allocator@PAVDOMAttr@xercesc_3_1@@@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z)
1>ArchDetails.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgURI_XSI" (__imp_?fgURI_XSI@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>ArchType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgURI_XSI" (__imp_?fgURI_XSI@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgURI_XSI" (__imp_?fgURI_XSI@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>TSPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::SchemaSymbols::fgURI_XSI" (__imp_?fgURI_XSI@SchemaSymbols@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>UniqueID.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static bool __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::equals(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *)" (__imp_?equals@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SA_NPBG0@Z)
1>Arch.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static bool __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::equals(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *)" (__imp_?equals@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SA_NPBG0@Z)
1>ArchDetails.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static bool __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::equals(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *)" (__imp_?equals@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SA_NPBG0@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl xsd::cxx::xml::dom::clear<char>(class xercesc_3_1::DOMElement &)" (??$clear@D@dom@xml@cxx@xsd@@YAXAAVDOMElement@xercesc_3_1@@@Z)
1>ArchType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static bool __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::equals(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *)" (__imp_?equals@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SA_NPBG0@Z)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static bool __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::equals(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *)" (__imp_?equals@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SA_NPBG0@Z)
1>TSPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static bool __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::equals(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *)" (__imp_?equals@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SA_NPBG0@Z)
1>UniqueID.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXMLNSURIName" (__imp_?fgXMLNSURIName@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>Arch.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXMLNSURIName" (__imp_?fgXMLNSURIName@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>ArchDetails.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXMLNSURIName" (__imp_?fgXMLNSURIName@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>ArchType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXMLNSURIName" (__imp_?fgXMLNSURIName@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXMLNSURIName" (__imp_?fgXMLNSURIName@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>TSPI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXMLNSURIName" (__imp_?fgXMLNSURIName@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB) referenced in function "public: __thiscall xsd::cxx::xml::string::~string(void)" (??1string@xml@cxx@xsd@@QAE@XZ)
1>UniqueID.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned long __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::stringLen(unsigned short const * const)" (__imp_?stringLen@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SAKQBG@Z)
1>Arch.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned long __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::stringLen(unsigned short const * const)" (__imp_?stringLen@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SAKQBG@Z)
1>ArchDetails.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned long __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::stringLen(unsigned short const * const)" (__imp_?stringLen@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SAKQBG@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl xsd::cxx::xml::transcode<char>(unsigned short const *)" (??$transcode@D@xml@cxx@xsd@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PBG@Z)
1>ArchType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned long __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::stringLen(unsigned short const * const)" (__imp_?stringLen@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SAKQBG@Z)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned long __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::stringLen(unsigned short const * const)" (__imp_?stringLen@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SAKQBG@Z)
1>TSPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned long __cdecl xercesc_3_1::XMLString::stringLen(unsigned short const * const)" (__imp_?stringLen@XMLString@xercesc_3_1@@SAKQBG@Z)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned short const * __thiscall xercesc_3_1::InputSource::getEncoding(void)const " (?getEncoding@InputSource@xercesc_3_1@@UBEPBGXZ)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned short const * __thiscall xercesc_3_1::InputSource::getPublicId(void)const " (?getPublicId@InputSource@xercesc_3_1@@UBEPBGXZ)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned short const * __thiscall xercesc_3_1::InputSource::getSystemId(void)const " (?getSystemId@InputSource@xercesc_3_1@@UBEPBGXZ)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall xercesc_3_1::InputSource::setEncoding(unsigned short const * const)" (?setEncoding@InputSource@xercesc_3_1@@UAEXQBG@Z)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall xercesc_3_1::InputSource::setPublicId(unsigned short const * const)" (?setPublicId@InputSource@xercesc_3_1@@UAEXQBG@Z)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall xercesc_3_1::InputSource::setSystemId(unsigned short const * const)" (?setSystemId@InputSource@xercesc_3_1@@UAEXQBG@Z)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMErrorHandler" (__imp_?fgDOMErrorHandler@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesLoadSchema" (__imp_?fgXercesLoadSchema@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaExternalNoNameSpaceSchemaLocation" (__imp_?fgXercesSchemaExternalNoNameSpaceSchemaLocation@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaExternalSchemaLocation" (__imp_?fgXercesSchemaExternalSchemaLocation@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesUserAdoptsDOMDocument" (__imp_?fgXercesUserAdoptsDOMDocument@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesHandleMultipleImports" (__imp_?fgXercesHandleMultipleImports@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaFullChecking" (__imp_?fgXercesSchemaFullChecking@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesSchema" (__imp_?fgXercesSchema@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMValidate" (__imp_?fgDOMValidate@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMElementContentWhitespace" (__imp_?fgDOMElementContentWhitespace@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMNamespaces" (__imp_?fgDOMNamespaces@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMEntities" (__imp_?fgDOMEntities@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMDatatypeNormalization" (__imp_?fgDOMDatatypeNormalization@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMComments" (__imp_?fgDOMComments@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class xercesc_3_1::DOMImplementation * __cdecl xercesc_3_1::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(unsigned short const *)" (__imp_?getDOMImplementation@DOMImplementationRegistry@xercesc_3_1@@SAPAVDOMImplementation@2@PBG@Z) referenced in function "struct xsd::cxx::xml::dom::auto_ptr<class xercesc_3_1::DOMDocument> __cdecl xsd::cxx::xml::dom::parse<char>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class xercesc_3_1::DOMErrorHandler &,class xsd::cxx::xml::properties<char> const &,unsigned long)" (??$parse@D@dom@xml@cxx@xsd@@YA?AU?$auto_ptr@VDOMDocument@xercesc_3_1@@@0123@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAVDOMErrorHandler@xercesc_3_1@@ABV?$properties@D@123@K@Z)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: __thiscall xercesc_3_1::InputSource::InputSource(unsigned short const * const,class xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager * const)" (__imp_??0InputSource@xercesc_3_1@@IAE@QBGQAVMemoryManager@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall xsd::cxx::xml::sax::std_input_source::std_input_source<char>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??$?0D@std_input_source@sax@xml@cxx@xsd@@QAE@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@6@@Z)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMXMLDeclaration" (__imp_?fgDOMXMLDeclaration@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMWRTFormatPrettyPrint" (__imp_?fgDOMWRTFormatPrettyPrint@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>T6EchoTEC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned short const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMWRTDiscardDefaultContent" (__imp_?fgDOMWRTDiscardDefaultContent@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBGB)
1>C:\Users\MCA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProjectAlpha\ProjectBlue_2005\Debug\ProjectBlue.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 31 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://C:\Users\MCA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProjectAlpha\ProjectBlue_2005\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>ProjectBlue - 62 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Compare the build and link settings between the successfully built example applications and the settings for the project producing the above errors, in particular compare the order of the libraries listed in any of the options. Reordering the libraries listed may help in resolving symbols the linker stalling on.

Comment: This is quite strange.  I moved all of the XML code into a dll and now the linker error has disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to set Properties->C/C++->Language->Treat WChar_t As Built in Type to No(/Zc:wchar_t-)

Comment: Do we need to set this option while compiling xerces library or our application ? How to set this option at command line

Comment: For compiling your application.  The command line option is probably something like the /z command up there.  You will have to research it to find out.